# Visualize the relationship between the binary and the categorical variables using appropriate plots in R

Tags: r, visualization, logistic-regression, categorical-data, binary-data

I have a dataframe, where the variable top10 has either value 0 (not in top 10) and 1 (in top 10). And a categorical variable label (Independent, Warner Music, Sony music, Universal music).

[image]

What would be an appropriate plot to visualize the relationship between these variables?

I was thinking about to visualize the probabilities of each label of being in top 10 (top10 == 1). But I have no idea how to do it...

That is what I started to do:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many potential solutions to your problem. Perhaps this approach suits your use-case?

```r
library(vcd)
#> Loading required package: grid
set.seed(300)
df <- data.frame(label = sample(c("Independent", "Warner Music", "Sony music", "Universal music"),
                                20, replace = TRUE),
                 top10 = as.character(sample(c(0, 0, 1), 20, replace = TRUE)))

df
#>              label top10
#> 1     Warner Music     0
#> 2     Warner Music     1
#> 3     Warner Music     0
#> 4      Independent     0
#> 5  Universal music     0
#> 6      Independent     1
#> 7      Independent     1
#> 8  Universal music     0
#> 9       Sony music     1
#> 10     Independent     1
#> 11 Universal music     1
#> 12     Independent     0
#> 13 Universal music     0
#> 14      Sony music     0
#> 15 Universal music     1
#> 16      Sony music     1
#> 17 Universal music     1
#> 18 Universal music     0
#> 19     Independent     1
#> 20     Independent     0
mosaic(data = table(df), ~ label + top10, highlighting = "top10",
       highlighting_fill = c("lightblue", "pink"),
       rot_labels=c(0,90,0,0), just_labels=c("left","right"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option in addition to the great suggestion already made by Jared. First I loaded the `tidyverse` for pipes and plotting. Then I randomly recreated your dataset, though I only used two categories of music here for simplicity, but you can of course add more.

```
#### Load Library for Plotting/Wrangling Data ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Set Seed and Recreate Data ####
set.seed(123)

label <- rep(
  c("Independent",
    "Universal Music"),
  11)

top10 <- rbinom(
  n=22,
  size=1,
  prob=.5
)

tib <- tibble(
  label,
  top10
)
tib
```

Then I plotted your data using this bar plot, using the binary as a factor and using the `position = "dodge"` code to split the binary by the label factor. The rest are just aesthetic stuff.

```
#### Plot Data ####
tib %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=label,
             fill=factor(top10)))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
  labs(x="Label",
       y="Top 10",
       title = "Bar Plot of Label Data",
       fill="Binary Variable")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred",
                               "darkblue"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Which gives you this visualization:

[image]

You can of course pretty up the labels as you feel.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept my answer or Jareds with the checkmark if it has answered your question.